# How to check if a value exists in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, find

I have the following dictionary in python:

```
d = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two', '5': 'five', '4': 'four'}
```

I need a way to find if a value such as "one" or "two" exists in this dictionary.

For example, if I wanted to know if the index "1" existed I would simply have to type:

```
"1" in d
```

And then python would tell me if that is true or false, however I need to do that same exact thing except to find if a value exists.

Answer (score 492, accepted):

```
>>> d = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two', '5': 'five', '4': 'four'}
>>> 'one' in d.values()
True
```

Out of curiosity, some comparative timing:

```
>>> T(lambda : 'one' in d.itervalues()).repeat()
[0.28107285499572754, 0.29107213020324707, 0.27941107749938965]
>>> T(lambda : 'one' in d.values()).repeat()
[0.38303399085998535, 0.37257885932922363, 0.37096405029296875]
>>> T(lambda : 'one' in d.viewvalues()).repeat()
[0.32004380226135254, 0.31716084480285645, 0.3171098232269287]
```

**EDIT:** And in case you wonder why... the reason is that each of the above returns a different type of object, which may or may not be well suited for lookup operations:

```
>>> type(d.viewvalues())
<type 'dict_values'>
>>> type(d.values())
<type 'list'>
>>> type(d.itervalues())
<type 'dictionary-valueiterator'>
```

**EDIT2:** As per request in comments...

```
>>> T(lambda : 'four' in d.itervalues()).repeat()
[0.41178202629089355, 0.3959040641784668, 0.3970959186553955]
>>> T(lambda : 'four' in d.values()).repeat()
[0.4631338119506836, 0.43541407585144043, 0.4359898567199707]
>>> T(lambda : 'four' in d.viewvalues()).repeat()
[0.43414998054504395, 0.4213531017303467, 0.41684913635253906]
```

Comment: i have no python at hand, could you rerun the tests with 'four' instead of 'one' ?

Comment: it wasn't necesarry after all, unless run on bigger dict. I guess overhead in values() is caused by copying the value list and in viewvalues() by maintaining the view alive.

Comment: Given the small size of `d`, the timings are effectively meaningless. In Python 3, `dict.values()` is a dictionary view, by default, and `dict.itervalues()` and `dict.viewvalues()` are gone. You could re-test this (with a larger dictionary) and use `list(d.values())` to get the Python 2 behaviour, and `iter(d.values())` to get the `dict.itervalues()` behaviour, but because both those versions require a global lookup and call, they'll absolutely be slower. Both do extra work that's not needed.

Answer (score 52):

In Python 3, you can use

```
"one" in d.values()
```

to test if `"one"` is among the values of your dictionary.

In Python 2, it's more efficient to use

```
"one" in d.itervalues()
```

instead.

Note that this triggers a linear scan through the values of the dictionary, short-circuiting as soon as it is found, so this is a lot less efficient than checking whether a key is present.

Comment: I know this is a *really* old answer, but just wanted to note that in Python 3 it is `values()` and not `itervalues()`.  I went into idiot mode for a while and tried to get `itervalues()` working in Python 3, before realising I'm an idiot.

Comment: @digitalformula that was exactly the trap i stepped into too, thank you very much

Answer (score 33):

Python dictionary has [get(key)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) function

```
>>> d.get(key)
```

For Example,

```
>>> d = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two', '5': 'five', '4': 'four'}
>>> d.get('3')
'three'
>>> d.get('10')
None
```

If your key does not exist, then it will return `None` value.

```
foo = d[key] # raise error if key doesn't exist
foo = d.get(key) # return None if key doesn't exist
```

Content relevant to versions less than 3.0 and greater than 5.0.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. OP asked about a value as in `key:value` and not key.

Answer (score 11):

Use dictionary views:

```
if x in d.viewvalues():
    dosomething()..
```

Answer (score 5):

Different types to check the values exists

```
d = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
"value10" in d.values() 
>> False
```

What if list of values

```
test = {'key1': ['value4', 'value5', 'value6'], 'key2': ['value9'], 'key3': ['value6']}
"value4" in [x for v in test.values() for x in v]
>>True
```

What if list of values with string values

```
test = {'key1': ['value4', 'value5', 'value6'], 'key2': ['value9'], 'key3': ['value6'], 'key5':'value10'}
values = test.values()
"value10" in [x for v in test.values() for x in v] or 'value10' in values
>>True
```

Comment: Don't use `value in [... list comprehension over  sequence ...]`, use `any(value in sequence ...)`, to avoid creating a list object you don't use for anything else, and to short-circuit when the value has been found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
d = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two', '5': 'five', '4': 'four'}
print("one" in d.values())
```

Or:

```
print(any([True for i,j in d1.items() if j == "one"]))
```

Answer (score -2):

In Python 3 you can use the `values()` function of the dictionary. It returns a view object of the values. This, in turn, can be passed to the `iter` function which returns an iterator object. The iterator can be checked using `in`, like this,

```py
'one' in iter(d.values())
```

Or you can use the view object directly since it is similar to a list

```
'one' in d.values()
```

Comment: There is *no point* in using `iter()` on a dictionary view; `in` will already use the object as an iterable (the type doesn't implement a dedicated `__contains__` method). The only difference between `'one' in iter(d.values())` and `'one in d.values()` is that you made Python do extra work (paying the cost of a global lookup for `iter`).