# Check if "word" is in string outputted from a function

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, if-statement

I have a function in variable x which returns

`{'activeTime': 106, 'deviceStatus': 'on', 'power': 'f29b:f19e', 'energy': 0.02, 'voltage': '7b2ba:7b366', 'deviceImg': ''}`

so then I put

```
if 'on' in x:
    print('on')
```

but it doesnt print on, what am i missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a value exists in a dictionary (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214932/how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-dictionary-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be

```
if 'on' in x.values()
```

as this is value and not key