# Determine if a value is in a list value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

**I have seen this question as a duplicate (seems all my questions have been duplicates so far)**

**My code**

```py
#UAA + UAG + UGA = STOP
n = 3

xdict = {
    "Phenylalanine": ["UUU", "UUC"],
    "Leucine": ["UUA", "CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "UUG"],
    "Isoleucine": ["AUU", "AUC", "AUA"],
    "Methionine": "AUG",
    "Valine": ["GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG"],
    "Serine": ["UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG"],
    "Proline": ["CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"],
    "Threonine": ["ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG"],
    "Alanine": ["GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG"],
    "Tyrosine": ["UAU", "UAC"],
    "Histidine": ["CAU", "CAC"],
    "Glutamine": ["CAA", "CAG"],
    "Asparagine": ["AAU", "AAC"],
    "Lysine": ["AAA", "AAG"],
    "Asparatic Acid": ["GAU", "GAC"],
    "Glutamic Acid": ["GAA", "GAG"],
    "Cysteine": ["UGU", "UGC"],
    "Trytophan": "UGG",
    "Arginine": ["CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AGG", "AGA"],
    "Serine": ["AGU", "AGC"],
    "Glycine": ["GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"]
}

lookup_dict = {k: key for key, values in xdict.items() for k in values}
a = input("Enter your DNA sequence: ")
a = a.upper()
print("Your DNA sequence is", a)
str(a)
RNA = a.replace("C", "G")
RNA = a.replace("A", "U")
RNA = a.replace("T", "A")
print("Your RNA strand is", RNA)

b = len(a)

if b % 3 == 0:
  for k in [a[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)]:
    if k in xdict.values(): #checking from other question
      print(lookup_dict[k], end=" ")
    elif k not in xdict.values(): #checking from other question
      print("I hate u")

elif b % 3 != 0:
  print("Try again.")
```

I have tried the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214932/how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-dictionary-python) link and it doesn't work for me. How do I detect if a value is in a dictionary in python?

Comment: @cricket_007 I will edit so that the checking is clear.

Comment: Note that your handling of single values is going to require extra code. You could just put them in a list of 1 to be consistent. Note also that iterating over the string gives you individual characters -- probably not intended. (also fixed by putting it in a list of 1)

Comment: You might also have a problem if the same sequence happens to appear somewhere inside two different lists. The lookup dict can only remember one of them, unless it also has lists for values.

Comment: It would help if you do not request input. Instead say exactly what value you're looking for, so we can see specifically why it's not being found.

Comment: Where is this data coming from? It certainly isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if a string is in a *list of lists* plus a few strings, so it would return false unless you try to search for those lone strings .

You'd either have to lookup the key, then check if your string is in that key's list value, or loop over all values (which you're already doing) instead like so, then check if it's *in the list* of the dictionary value

```
if b % 3 == 0:
  for _, values in xdict.items():
    for k in (a[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)):
      if k in values:
        print(lookup_dict[k], end=" ")
      else
        print("I hate u")
```

Comment: The key of the lookup dict is created after iterating over the original value's multiple values. (although that goes wrong on the single strings)

Comment: @cricket_007 When I print this out it repeats "I hate u" for a while and then my first part of answer then the next part and so on until it comes out right... how do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of the lookup dict, but my answer is more focused on the first dict

Comment: The purpose of the lookup dict is because they want to search the values. You can't do that on a dict, which is designed to quickly find things by the key.

Comment: @cricket_007 The lookup dict definition is to find the values in the dictionary. It doesn't do error handling, however.

Comment: @cricket_007 Now it comes up like this: ```Glycine I hate u Glycine I hate u Glycine I hate u```

Comment: @Guy you could add a break in the loop, but it currently attempts to scan all items, so you would see duplicates, yes

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: @cricket_007 I mean that is the "I hate u" part keeps coming up after the word

Comment: @Guy and like I explained, you could add a break statement to exit the loop before that gets printed, or you can edit the logic however you want... The point of the answer is to fix the in statement, not solve the overall problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pandas, it's a good approach for searching like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df =  pd.DataFrame(list(xdict.items()))


def lookupKey(df, key):
  return df[df[1].apply(lambda x: True if key in x else x) == True][0].reset_index()[0][0]

lookupKey(df, 'CGU')
# 'Arginine'
```

Comment: `[df[1].apply(lambda x: True if key in x else x) == True]` --> `[df[1].apply(lambda x: True if key in x else x) is True]` --> `[df[1].apply(lambda x: True if key in x else x)]` Also I can't manage to build a DataFrame like that, I get `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`.