# How to search dictionary with multiple vales in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Python, I have a questions over searching dictionary in Python.

My file looks like below, and I want to search for

name contains 'Jige', size is '29' (that's row 1)
and name contains 'Trim' , size is '31' (last row)

not sure how to write the code in Python3. It'd be the best that has a search_key variable takes argument from users

Thanks in advance!

My file:

```
[{'name': 'Jige 29 clutch', 'price': '250', 'size': '29'},
 {'name': 'Her 33 bag', 'price': '530', 'size': '33'},
 {'name': 'Tote 24 bag', 'price': '480', 'size': '24'},
 {'name': 'Yona 34 bag', 'price': '400', 'size': '34'},
 {'name': 'Trim 24 bag', 'price': '390', 'size': '24'},
 {'name': 'Trim double 31 bag', 'price': '400', 'size': '31'}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a value exists in a dictionary (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214932/how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-dictionary-python)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply convert it to dataFrame like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
# name contains 'Jige', size is '29' and name contains 'Trim' , size is '31'
df[(df['name'].str.contains('Jige')) | (df['name'].str.contains('Trim')) |  (df['size'] == 31) ]
```

I used or (|) for showing data, but you can use and(&)

[image]

Comment: Please dont use images as answers. Use code (as text)

Comment: I did use code, and I show the image for the results, what is wrong with images?

Answer (score 0):

> and I want to search for name contains 'Jige', size is '29' and name contains 'Trim' , size is '31'

There are no records that meets the condition you ask for.
If you switch the `and` operator to `or` operator  you will get few records.

```
data= [{'name': 'Jige 29 clutch', 'price': '250', 'size': '29'},
 {'name': 'Her 33 bag', 'price': '530', 'size': '33'},
 {'name': 'Tote 24 bag', 'price': '480', 'size': '24'},
 {'name': 'Yona 34 bag', 'price': '400', 'size': '34'},
 {'name': 'Trim 24 bag', 'price': '390', 'size': '24'},
 {'name': 'Trim double 31 bag', 'price': '400', 'size': '31'}]

filtered_data = [e for e in data if 'Jige' in e['name'] and 'Trim' in e['name'] and e['size'] == '29' and e['size'] == '31']

print(f'filtered_data: {filtered_data}')

filtered_data2 = [e for e in data if 'Jige' in e['name'] or 'Trim' in e['name'] or e['size'] == '29' or e['size'] == '31']

print(f'filtered_data2: {filtered_data2}')
```